# Certificate api name

Tags: webservices, certificates

For example, I do the following :

1. Export from Keystore the certs located in my Prod
2. Import from Keystore the certs to my Sandbox

Anyone knows why during this transaction the api names (and labels) are lowercased ? It's annoying for the integration of the webservices. If anyone has an advice on how to avoid that... ?

Example : 
API_Certificate gives api_certificate